# Neo4j GC overhead limit

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I build a neo4j graph. The size is about 5 GB. When I want to add a relation to each node by using a cypher query like `match (a)-[:know]-(b),(b)-[:know]-(c) merge (a)-[:maybe_know]-(c)` , I get a `GC overhead limit` error. I don't want to increase the memory for neo4j. Is there some way to update nodes step by step? Like firstly, 5000 nodes, then another 5000 nodes... Or do you have some other suggestions about this?

Comment: `LIMIT 5000` maybe? If the query is stable (produces the same ordering each time) you could follow up with `SKIP 5000 LIMIT 5000` then `SKIP 10000 LIMIT 5000` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @twobit says, limit your batches to something manageable but also only match things that have not already been matched.  i.e. if `a` and `c` already `know` one another or the `maybe_know` relationship has already been created between them then never match them again. Yould could also make sure the id of one is greater than the other which would ensure you don't make the same match twice (once in each direction).

```
match (a)-[:know]-(b),(b)-[:know]-(c)
where a <> c
  and not (a)-[:know|maybe_know]-(c)
  and id(a) > id(c)
merge (a)-[:maybe_know]-(c)
limit 1000
```

Comment: A question here, does the position of the LIMIT matter? Would there be any performance improvement if we used a WITH after the WHERE with a LIMIT, then did the merge, or is it taking care of that optimization under the hood?

Comment: I would expect them to be approximately the same.  One way to find out though would be to profile each version on the exact same dataset.